# Formatting hyperlinks in Python

Tags: python, hyperlink, formatting

I am trying to format a hyperlink that goes out in an MMS so far I have this

```
phoneLink = "<a href='tel:180055512127'>Click Here To Call Support 1-800-555-1212</a>"
sLink = '<a href="{0}">{0}</a>'.format(phoneLink)
```

This works sort of it sends the MMS with the phone link which works the only problem is it looks line this in the final message:

```
<a href='tel:180055512127'>Click Here To Call Support 1-800-555-1212</a>"
```

It should be just:

```
Click Here To Call Support 1-800-555-1212
```

I thought there was a hyperlink format function in Python, but I can't seem to find it. 
How do I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're using `format()` wrong. Check out the value of `sLink` after your code runs.

```
>>> phoneLink = "<a href='tel:180055512127'>Click Here To Call Support 1-800-555-1212</a>"
>>> sLink = '<a href="{0}">{0}</a>'.format(phoneLink)
>>> sLink
'<a href="<a href=\'tel:180055512127\'>Click Here To Call Support 1-800-555-1212</a>"><a href=\'tel:180055512127\'>Click Here To Call Support 1-800-555-1212</a></a>'
>>>
```

You are putting the value of `phoneLink` in `<a href="...">` and between `<a>` and `</a>`. I think you were trying to do something along the lines of:

```
prettyPhoneNumber = '1-800-555-1212'
phoneNumber = '180055512127'
phoneLink = '<a href="tel:{0}">Click Here To Call Support {1}</a>'
sLink = phoneLink.format(phoneNumber, prettyPhoneNumber)
```

The result of this one is:

```
>>> sLink
'<a href="180055512127">Click Here To Call Support 1-800-555-1212</a>'
```